# How do I search my table for a form variable and add to the table if not found but increment the value by the user specified quantity if it is found?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following form in my main page:

```
<left><h2><font color="ghostwhite">Enter Part</font></h2></left>
<form action="addpart.php" method="post">
<font color="ghostwhite">Date:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp& &nbsp&nbsp</font> <input type="text" name="date" /><br>
<font color="ghostwhite">Part Number:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font> <input type="text" name="partnum" /><br>
<font color="ghostwhite">Location:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font> <input type="text" name="location" /><br>
<font color="ghostwhite">Quantity:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font> <input type="text" name="quantity" /><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have the following php that I'm wanting to do the following:

1. Insert the $date entered by the user into the date column in the project database.
2. Insert the $partnumber entered by the user into the part_name column in the project database.
3. Insert the $location entered by the user into the location column in the project database.
4. Insert the $quantity entered by the user into the quantity column in the project database.

Here is the problem I'm having. I can't figure out how to search the part_name column for what the user entered and if it's not there enter it in with the quantity the user specified, but increment by the user specified amount if it is found.

I'm thinking it would be something like:

```
$dup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parts(part_name) WHERE VALUE($partnumber)

if ($dup)
    {
   mysql_query("UPDATE parts SET part_name = part_name + $quantity");
    }
else
    {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO parts (time, part_name, location, quantity) VALUES($date,   $partnumber, $location, $quantity)");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `select * from parts WHERE part_name=$partnumber`, though note that this vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: so it should be something like this:

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Should do what your asking

No comments on the html.